# Installing Redis 4 (latest stable version) on windows

Tags: windows, redis

How can I install Redis latest stable version (4.0) on Windows? 
I checked MSOpenTech's GitHub page it has an older version and archived.

Comment: same question here: so what I saw, there was no forward branch for the 4.x (release 2017-06) for the winport-github yet at the time of writing this (2018-01-31). Also the last commit to the winport-github (officially 3.2x) was in 2016 :(

Answer (score 9):

If you are interested in native version of Redis for Windows - please check the updated fork of the mentioned MSOpenTech's repository here: https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases

This is a merge of latest 3.2.100 from [MSOpenTech/redis](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis) and original Redis 4.0.2. Please read the details of what is and what is not supported at the moment and note that this is still in "alpha" state.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Docker for Windows`](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows). Then [install `redis`](https://store.docker.com/images/redis) the normal way.

```
docker run --name some-redis -p 6379 -d redis
```